Oracle SQL - Change CASE expression from months to specific dates (BETWEEN)
I am trying to convert an existing CASE expression that is looking at months and instead have it look at exact dates.
CASE
    WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <60 and to_char(read_date,'mm') in ('06','07','08','09') then 'Y'
    WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <90 and to_char(read_date,'mm') in ('01','02','03','04','05','10','11','12') then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END as Keep_Flag

My changes run, but the results are incorrect
CASE
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <60 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '6-15' AND '10-15' then 'Y'
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <90 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '6-14' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END as Keep_Flag

Thank for any help adjusting.
The results of the CASE expressions are used to filter the data in a WHERE statement
WHERE keep_flag = 'Y'


Please provide some sample input data and the expected result. To me, both queries look very strange and I doubt that's a good idea, but hard to tell without further information.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

I tried reproducing your issue with the assumption read_date is in the format   DD-MM-YY. Your query is comparing strings.
You can use TO_DATE like so
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD'), 'MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_DATE('06-15', 'MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('10-15', 'MM-DD') 

For the second condition
BETWEEN '10-16' AND '6-14'

Do you intend to include dates between 16th October and 14th June or the other way round i,e dates between 14th June and 16th October.I assume you want to add dates between  16th October and 14th June since June to October is included in the first condition.
AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'

Fiddle
Sample Input



ID
REG_CON
TAGG_READING
READ_DATE




1
1
10
20-JUN-24


2
4
20
10-APR-24


3
4
30
15-AUG-24


4
4
40
25-DEC-24


5
3
50
05-OCT-24



SELECT id, reg_con, tagg_reading, read_date,
CASE
    WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 60 
         AND TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' THEN 'Y'
    WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading < 90 
         AND (TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' OR TO_CHAR(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14') THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS Keep_Flag
FROM test;

Output



ID
REG_CON
TAGG_READING
READ_DATE
KEEP_FLAG




1
1
10
20-JUN-24
Y


2
4
20
10-APR-24
Y


3
4
30
15-AUG-24
N


4
4
40
25-DEC-24
N


5
3
50
05-OCT-24
N




Thank you for the response and also the fiddle link. I did not know about that, so I will use in the future to provide data to work with. I'll test and reply back. Thanks.

You are welcome @Brent, here are some of the useful links
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

The fiddle link was very helpful to understand! Thank  you

There are two immediate problems with your second case expression.
Firstly, by default date elements are zero-padded, so if read_date was 2024-06-15 the conversion to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') would give '06-15', not '6-15'.
Secondly, the order of the values matter for BETWEEN, as mentioned in the documentation:

If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty.

So when compared as strings, no date values will be between '6-15' and '10-15', because '1' is alphabetically before '6' - and nothing matches BETWEEN '6' AND '1' because '1' (expr3) < '6' (expr2) which makes that interval empty.
Some values will be matched between '10-16' and '6-14', but only those up to '12-31', so only about half the range you're looking for. Anything between January and September will have first character '0', so won't be in that range.
You could split your second match into two parts, using two-digit month numbers:
CASE
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <60 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' then 'Y'
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <90 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '06-14' then 'Y'
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <90 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '10-16' AND '12-31' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END as Keep_Flag

Or you could keep one range, but use NOT BETWEEN to exclude the ‘06-15’ to ‘10-16’ range instead:
CASE
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <60 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' then 'Y'
   WHEN reg_con * tagg_reading <90 and to_char(read_date, 'MM-DD') NOT BETWEEN '06-15' AND '10-15' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END as Keep_Flag

This still looks odd, but without sample data and expected results it's unclear if it will do what you actually want. In general it's better to compare dates against dates (or date ranges), but you're ignoring the year which is a problem. It's also possible you could do something with quarter numbers, adding days to the values before converting for comparison, but again it's unclear.

Thank your for the response and details on the zero padding issue. I'll review and replay back. Thanks again!
